# Numpy.where on an array of strings using regex

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
array = ['A0','A1','A2','A3','A4','B0','B1','C0']
```

and want to obtain an array which is true for values with an A followed by a number ranging from 0 to 2.

So far, this is the way I do it:

```
selection = np.where ((array == 'A0') | (array == 'A1') | (array == 'A2'), 1, 0)
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this by using e.g., a regular expresion like:

```
selection = np.where (array == 'A[0-1]', 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think numpy if your best solution here.  You can accomplish this using built-in python tools such as `map`.

```py
import re

array = ['A0','A1','A2','A3','A4','B0','B1','C0']
p = r'A[0-2]'

list(map(lambda x: bool(re.match(p, x)), array))
# returns
[True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False]

# to get an array:
np.array(list(map(lambda x: bool(re.match(p, x)), array)))
# returns:
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Comment: You can pass it through the numpy array constructor.  See the update.

Answer (score 5):

If using pandas is an option:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array(['A0','A1','A2','A3','A4','B0','B1','C0'])
pd.Series(a).str.match(r'A[0-2]')
# 0     True
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# 4    False
# 5    False
# 6    False
# 7    False
# dtype: bool
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but I need a purely numpy approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not more complicated than `A0`, `A1` and `A2`, you can use

```
a = np.array(['A0','A1','A2','A3','A4','B0','B1','C0'])
np.in1d(a, ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'])
# array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False])
```

Comment: It is more complicated than just that. I tried to post a simple example... but I need to set other conditions involving other numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try vectorization with blend of `re` :

```
import re
array = ['A0','A1','A2','A3','A4','B0','B1','C0']

y = np.vectorize(lambda y, x: bool(re.compile(x).match(y)))
selection = np.where(y(array, 'A[0-2]'), 1, 0)
print(selection)

#output:
[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: You don't need to use a ternary expression, you can just use `bool(re.compile(x).match(y))`

Comment: Also, `np.vectorize()` is only for convenience, it doesn't provide any speedup over a `for` loop.

Comment: @NilsWerner I used it for its literal use, i.e. to vectorize a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `list comprehension`:

```
r = re.compile('A[0-2]')
selection = np.array([1 if re.match(r, i) else 0 for i in array])
```